# Calling a method within another method in the same class in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, self

In the following class, I would expect the output to be:

```
here
generating spike
generate spike 2
some data
```

Instead, the output is:

```
here
generating spike
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Class:

```
class InjectAnomaly:
    def generate_drop(self):
        print('generate drop 2')
        print(self.data)

        return

    def generate_spike(self):
        print('generate spike 2')
        print(self.data)

        return

    def inject(self):
        spike_or_drop = self.type

        if spike_or_drop is 'spike':
            print('Generating spike')
            self.generate_spike() 

        elif spike_or_drop is 'drop':
            print('Generating drop')
            self.generate_drop()

    def __init__(self, type, data):
        self.type = type
        self.data = data

        if self.type is not 'none':
            print('here')
            self.inject()
```

I've seen other questions on Stack Overflow addressing the same thing, and I don't know what I am doing differently.
inject() gets called, then it identifies the spike

Comment: Output of what? You have a class, but you aren't showing how you create an instance of that class or invoke a method that produces the observed output.

Comment: The use of `is`, though, is a big red flag. There are no language guarantees that any two occurrences of `'spike'`, for instance, will be to the same object. Use `==`. Given `x = 'spike'`, `x is 'spike'` may or may not be true (it's not in your case, apparently), but `x == 'spike'` will always be true.

Comment: for starters, `spike_or_drop is 'spike'`  is incorrect. You should **never** use `is`, which is for *identity* checks, to do an *equality* check. Use `spike_or_drop == 'spike':`

Comment: @chepner Sorry, this is how I created an instance of that class: `inject_anomaly = InjectAnomaly(args.injectAnomaly, data)` And the method is invoked via __init__()

Comment: but you were both right - the problem was the `is`. Thank you!